# How can I stop seeing the question "How do I calculate someone's age in C#?"

Tags: discussion, related-questions

The question [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) is shown in the right-hand panel under "Related".  Is it possible to stop seeing this? After seeing it for hundreds of times, it really is useless.

Comment: The question "Unrelated 'related questions' keep appearing because of high vote count'" is definitely in the same spirit as my question above, but no action has been taken for the problem.

Comment: The site founder fretted about this a long time ago.  The algorithm he used is straight-forward, he removes the common words from a question ("the", "is", etc) and then looks for other questions that have a good match with the remaining words.  Problem was (and is), on some questions there were so few words left that they'd always match a well-written question.  The site would look very different if he had taken the next logical step: rejecting the question.  But of course you can do that yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you Hans Passant, you are *always* very helpful.